# No image showup using expressJs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I do have a small issue i can't solved despite reading on internet.

I'm learning node.js, express.js, ejs.

I create a small app that tries to display a dynamic webpage on my local server. 
The code is working but not the display of the pictures! (the stylesheet works fine)

here is my index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <% include partials/head %>
</head>
<body class="container">

    <header>
        <% include partials/header %>
    </header>

    <main>
            <h1><%= title %> </h1>
        <img scr="/images/logo_small.jpg" alt="logo" />
            <p> Welcome to <%= title %></p>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <% include partials/footer %>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

In the main apps i wrote:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

And finally i put the images in ./public/images/logo_small.jpg.

The display shows "logo" instead of the pictures. When I go this URL

> http://localhost:3000/images/logo_small.jpg

Firefox shows me the image. it is frustrating!

I miss something here, but i don't see what. Any idea ?

Comment: You have `scr` proeprty instead of `src` in your `img` tag

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot.. (pass from frustrated to ashamed)